# bash command to echo the next directory up in a sub directory?

Tags: linux, bash, file-management

What I want is to take a directory, `dirname/subdirname/filename` and return `dirname/subdirname/`.

This is in Linux with `bash`.

I did some googling and found nothing because I can't express my ideas to the search engine properly.

Comment: `result="${dir%/*}"` or, slower / less-efficiently, `result=$(dirname "$dir")`

Comment: Per @CharlesDuffy comment https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html